# Adding Magento custom option fields with a module

Tags: php, magento

I recently started a new job with a tiny company running a niche website on Magento. This is my first module, and I have no experience with Magento but can do pretty solid PHP and what have you. I'm having a hard time figuring out what it is I need to extend and how.

What I need to do is make a help bubble display beside every option that needs a help bubble, and when clicked have it display an image. In the backend this would be a drop-down box in each custom option box within every Product. Getting the actual functionality of the box isn't an issue; I'm just lost as to how to get the box in there in the first place.

In terms of what I've tried, I looked at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option` and overriding the `getOptionValues()` method, but there are getters in there that claim to live in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option` and aren't.

My question is, what do I override and where can I find it? Any help at all would be great; thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess you are talking about lines like `$value['id'] = $option->getOptionId();`. These get*() methods are magic methods, as you know Varien_Object class is parent class for all magento models classes, see `__call()` method in Varien_Object class. Please elaborate, what do you need (or what you don't know how to do) exactly.

Comment: Ok, so you wrote layout update in your module backend layout update xml file to replace adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options block with your own block (you can't replace Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option via layout update directly as we both know). In this your block class in `_prepareLayout()` you load your block (instead of 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option') which you extended from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option, right? So, what you wish to do in getOptionValues() now? This part is still unclear for me, sorry :(

Comment: The $value array at line 203; don't I need to put in another cell?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean "another cell"? Code on this line and below prepares data for this drop-down box: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/inputtype.jpg, it is generated in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options block, see its template \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml, `$this->getOptionValues()` is called near the end of this file.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, I think I know what I need to do. Thanks a lot. (If you give an answer, I can accept it whereas I can't with a comment.)

Comment: I wish I know what was the answer for your question :) I'll try to summarize all what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to summarize our discussion here.

1. Write layout update in your module backend layout update xml file to replace adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options block with your own block (let's call it A) (you can't replace Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option via layout update directly as we both know).
2. Extend your block from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option (let's call this block B) and load this your block class in _prepareLayout() method of you block class A.
3. Do what you need in getOptionValues() of block B.
4. Make changes in block B template file (copy content of \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\opti‌​on.phtml to your template file and make needed changes).